# install_github R issue, SSL connect error

Tags: r, rcurl, devtools, httr

I am trying to install a package from github in R but am getting an error I havent been able to solve.

```
>devtools::install_github("hadley/multidplyr")

Downloading GitHub repo hadley/multidplyr@master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
SSL connect error
```

This is on a 64bit Windows 7 enterprise machine. I tried to turn off verificaiton of the peer's ssl certificate with the following:

```
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
```

This didn't change the error message unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] httr_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] R6_2.1.1       magrittr_1.5   tools_3.2.2    curl_0.9.4    
[5] memoise_0.2.1  stringi_1.0-1  stringr_1.0.0  digest_0.6.8  
[9] devtools_1.9.1
```

Comment: You may have an older R version with https support.

Comment: Can you please show the sessionInfo()?

Comment: And when I wrote _with_ above I did of course mean _without_ ....

Comment: I have edited the question to include the session info.